# Best possible way to merge two pandas dataframe using a key and divide it

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes.

df1

```
       unique  numerator
        23       4
        29       10
```

df2

```
       unique  denominator

        23       2
        29       5
```

Now I want like this

```
    unique    result
     23         2
     29         2
```

Without using loops... or whichever is the most efficient way. Its a division numerator/denominator

Comment: Can you explain how you get the result? It is exactly the same as `df2` (apart from the column name)

Comment: Why is the result not 2 for both rows?

Comment: Your title bears little resemblance to your question you need to update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set the index to `unique` for both dfs then you can just divide the 2 columns:

```
In [6]:
df.set_index('unique')['numerator']/df1.set_index('unique')['denominator']

Out[6]:
unique
23    2
29    2
dtype: float64
```

or merge on 'unique' and then do the calc as normal:

```
In [9]:
merged=df.merge(df1, on='unique')
merged

Out[9]:
   unique  numerator  denominator
0      23          4            2
1      29         10            5

In [10]:
merged['result'] = merged['numerator']/merged['denominator']
merged

Out[10]:
   unique  numerator  denominator  result
0      23          4            2       2
1      29         10            5       2
```

Answer (score 2):

EdChum has provided 2 good options.

An alternative is in using the div() or divide() function.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame ({'unique':[23,29],'numerator': [4,10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'unique':[23,29],'denominator': [2,5]})

df1.set_index('unique',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('unique',inplace=True)

print df1.div(df2['denominator'],axis=0)
```

---

An important thing to note is that you need to divide by a series aka df2['denominator']

`df1.div(df2,axis=0)` will produce

```
        denominator  numerator
unique                        
23              NaN        NaN
29              NaN        NaN
```

this is because the label 'denominator' in df2 does not match 'numerator' in df1. However a series does not have *column label* as it were and its values are *broadcast* across the columns of df1.